# Cannot load a User Control to Tool Box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

When we add a user control dll to the Tool Box of Visual Studio, We are getting the following error message. The issue occurs in WinXP 64 bit. The user control refers a module named ICEConnect200Bridge. The assembly ICEConnect200Bridge is a C++ CLI module. The user control was built using 'Any CPU' platform.

What build option should I give for ICEConnect200Bridge? 
What should I do to identify the exact cause of the issue?

Could not load file or assembly 'ICEConnect200Bridge, Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Comment: Not really a fix, but do you really need to add the control to the VS Toolbox? You can simply reference the Dll file from the project and add it in code.

Comment: CodingBarfield: In that case how can I add the user control to a windows form in another application?

Comment: Visual Studio is a 32-bit program.  It cannot load C++/CLI assemblies that are compiled to target x64.  You must create a Win32 build for the assembly.

Comment: @Maanu just add it in MyForm.cs like the other controls are added in MyForm.designer.cs

Comment: @Hans Passant: The ICEConnect200 Bridge has some callback interfaces. The user controls implement the interfaces. I moved the interfaces to a .Net assembly. Now Visual studio can add the user controls to the Tool Box. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building ICEConnect200Bridge, put the target specifically to x86 instead of Any CPU. Visual Studio is compiled for x86 and installed in **Program Files (x86)** and does not accept controls in its toolbox that are not explicitly compiled for the same target.